# How to improve my neural network accuracy function such that keras lazy evaluation is possible

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I currently have my neural network accuracy function (and neural network) as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
import numpy as np

def predoneacc(y_true, y_pred):
    y_nptrue = y_true.numpy()
    y_nppredinit = y_pred.numpy()

    y_nppred = np.round(y_nppredinit)
    return arr1eq(y_nptrue,y_nppred)

def arr1eq(y_true, y_pred):
    k = 0.0
    count1 = 0.0
    for i in range(len(y_true)):
        for j in range(len(y_true[0])):
            if y_pred[i][j] == 1.0:
                count1 = count1+1.0
                if y_true[i][j] == 1.0:
                    k = k+1.0
    if(count1==0.0): return 0
    else: return k/count1

tap=5

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.LSTM(300, input_shape=(tap,45)),
    keras.layers.Dense(45, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=[predoneacc], run_eagerly=True)
model.fit(x,y,epochs=150) #x,y data properly given input/output shape required by the network
```

But this accuracy function cannot be used by TensorFlow keras [`tensorflow.keras.models.compile()`](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) unless `run_eagerly=True` is set because `.numpy()` is used. The code runs up to `model.fit()`, which complains that I have to set eager evaluation on. So I would like to re-code my accuracy function so that `.compile()` can accept the accuracy function without setting `run_eagerly=True` in `.compile()`.

What would be the way out? my accuracy function currently simply returns number of accurate 1 predictions divided by total number of 1 predictions in binary classification problems, with output layer activation function being sigmoid.

I have tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: can you show what `model.compile` currently looks like? and provide some dummy data?

Comment: @AloneTogether model.compile is a Keras compile .compile() function

Comment: @AloneTogether That's true. That's the thing - I just wanted to see how the rounded version of `y_pred` fares relative to `y_true`  in terms of accurate 1s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this could work for you:

```py
def arr1eq(y_true, y_pred):
  y_pred = tf.round(y_pred)
  count = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.where(tf.equal(y_pred, 1.0)), 1), dtype=tf.int32))
  k = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.where(tf.equal(tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.float32), 1.0)), 1), dtype=tf.int32))
  return tf.where(count==0, tf.constant(0.0), tf.constant(tf.cast(k/count, dtype=tf.float32)))
```

`y_pred` is first rounded to the nearest integer, then I calculate check where `y_pred` has 1.0 values. The number of occurrences is summed up in the variable `count`. The same is done to `y_true` without rounding.

Here is a simplified version (sorry for any confusion):

```py
def arr1eq2(y_true, y_pred):
  y_pred = tf.round(y_pred)
  y_pred_indices = tf.where(tf.equal(y_pred, 1.0))
  count = tf.shape(y_pred_indices)[0]
  k = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.gather_nd(y_true, y_pred_indices), 1), dtype=tf.int32))
  return tf.where(count==0, tf.constant(0.0), tf.constant(tf.cast(k/count, dtype=tf.float32)))
```